# Reflection Java assistance

Tags: java, reflection, retention

I have a reflection thing that goes out and finds all classes with an annotation called @Song and a name of charge. How would I make this go into org.alexwebber.songs and find all the classes with @Song and get all their names into a array? Thanks!

```
new Reflections("org.alexwebber.musicMaker.songs").getTypesAnnotatedWith(Song.class);
    for ( Class<?> cls : new Reflections("org.alexwebber.musicMaker.songs").getTypesAnnotatedWith(Song.class) ) {
        Song annotation = (Song) cls.getDeclaredAnnotation(Song.class);
        if ( annotation != null && annotation.Name().equals("Charge")) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            Object song = cls.getConstructor().newInstance();
            break;
        }
```

Comment: Whats the issue you are facing with the above code?

Comment: I am not having a issue, I want an array made of strings of all of the classes with @Song Names.

Answer (score 0):

The below code might not compile.. I typed it on github.. is this what you were looking for? You had most of the work done already.. If you were looking for something else, please update the question..

```
Set<Class<?>> classes=new Reflections("pkg prefix").getTypesAnnotatedWith(Song.class)
List<String> chargeNames=new ArrayList()<>;
for(Class<?> clz:classes){
    Song annotation = (Song) cls.getDeclaredAnnotation(Song.class);
    if(annotation!=null) chargeNames.add(annotation.Name());
}

String[] chargenamesar= chargeNames.toArray(new String[chargeNames.size()])
```